# Cant Vertically Center non anchor tags in bootstrap nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap top navigation bar, and all the  tags within the  inside the nav center nicely, however i have an image, and a toggle switch that i cant seem to vertically center in the navigation. I have tried lots of various custom css but havent had any luck. Ideally i want to make a class for this, nav-center-ele.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header nav-center-ele">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
<!-- THIS IMAGE WONT VERTICALLY CENTER -->
                <img class="img-responsive nav-center-ele" src="./assets/img/Logo.png" alt="Logo" width="150" height="30">
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#!/about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <!--<li><a href="#!/home">home</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="#!/foo">foo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!/bar">Bar</a></li>
                    <li>
                    <!-- Rounded switch wont center!! -->
                        <label class="switch">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="darkModeSlider">
                            <span class="slider round nav-center-ele"></span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Use `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:middle;` to get everything vertically aligned to the middle

Comment: Bootstrap 3 i updated the tag, and @AshokVishwakarma that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `navbar-text` class to give it the proper vertical padding...

https://www.codeply.com/go/Z914uQtCSE

```
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <!--<li><a href="#!/home">home</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="#!/foo">foo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!/bar">Bar</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar-text">
                    <!-- Rounded switch wont center!! -->
                        <label class="switch">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="darkModeSlider">
                            <span class="slider round nav-center-ele"></span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
         </ul>
```